# What is a representation of the Lie algebra sl(3,R) in 2 by 2 matrices?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Do we have a representation of the Lie algebra sl(3, R) in 2 by 2 matrices? What is the minimal dimensional representation of it. or in general how do we know the minimal dimension representation of Lie algebra sl(n,r)?

Comment: The minimal dimension of a nontrivial representation is $n$. This follows once you show that these Lie algebras are simple, since then a nontrivial representarion must be faithful.